# Can't close h5py file

Tags: freeze, hdf5, mpi4py

I'm writting in a h5py file in parallel using mpi4py. I notice that the programs seems to freeze when i try to close the h5file. Do you have an idea what can cause this issue?

Thanks a lot 
I process as follow :

```
`f = h5py.File('tttt.hdf5', 'w',driver= 'mpio', comm=Comm,libver='latest')
f.create_dataset('Spect',shape = (100,),maxshape=(100000,),dtype='f', chunks = True)
###### spect calculation ##########
###### spect recording ############
f['Spect'].resize(np.array(Spect.shape))
f['Spect'][:] = Spect
print fclosing
f.close() # Here the program seems to be stuck 
print "finish" # doesn't appear in the control `
```

Comment: Are there any error messages? If so, please copy and paste into the question.

Comment: No unfortunatly there is no error...